# ¿Cómo guardo datos en un vector en C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy intentando guardar una lista(serie) de números en un vector pero me marca error en el "cin" de notas y no se como solucionarlo. Gracias.

```
  vector<double> notas{};
  double n;
  cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes a añadir: "<<endl; cin>>n;
  notas.resize(n);
  cout<<"Ingrese las notas: "<<endl;
  cin>>notas;
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿ Podrías indicar el error exacto junto a la línea en la que aparece ? Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, el error aparece en el cin>>notas; osea en la ultima linea, y justo me lo marca en el cin, y dice: std::istream std::cin
ningún operador ">>" coincide con estos operandos -- los tipos de operando son: std::istream >> std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu estás esperando que el compilador haga "magia" y adivine cuántos elementos debe almacenar en el vector...

No existe ninguna sobrecarga para el operador `>>` de `cin` que admita un vector. Y tiene su razón de ser: La librería estándar de C++ intenta ser genérica. Una funcion que rellene automáticamente todas las posiciones de un vector deja de ser genérica:

- ¿Y si solo quiero rellenar un par de posiciones del vector?
- ¿Y si el vector ya tiene algunos valores válidos?
- ¿Y si los valores deben rellenarse desde el final del vector al principio?

Y esta es una de las razones por las que la sobrecarga que intentas invocar no existe.

Puedes probar a implementarla tu (no es recomendable en este caso):

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, std::vector<double> & out)
{
  // ¿Cómo rellenamos el vector?
}
```

O puedes obviar dicha implementación y hacerlo directamente:

```
std::cout << "Ingrese las notas\n"; // Es preferibla usar '\n' a std::endl
for( double & valor : notas )
    std::cin >> valor;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.